# Retrieve the latest data by using API link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

Goal:
Every time when I press the Button 'Test' you always need to fetch fresh data from backend by using API link. Then it should be displayed on the modalform.

Problem:
When I change the text in the input box or delete all text and then closing the modal and then click on the button Test again. The latest changes of what I have done would display. It shouldn't be happening because you always should get the latest data from backend by using API link.

Question:
How should the code always retrieve the data by using api link when you always press on the button 'test'?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-byxk6x?file=index.tsx

Thank you!

---

index.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import { TestModalForm } from './TestModalForm';

interface AppProps {}
interface AppState {
  name: string;
}

const App: FC<AppProps> = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
        Test
      </button>
      <br />

      <TestModalForm />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

TestModalForm.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const TestModalForm = () => {
  const [inputid, setInputid] = useState('');
  const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function FetchData() {
      var data = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
      ).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      });
      setInputid(data.id);
      setInputTitle(data.title);
    }

    FetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleIdInput = (e: any) => {
    setInputid(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleTitleInput = (e: any) => {
    setInputTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  // Reset Input Field handler
  const resetInputField = () => {
    setInputid('');
    setInputTitle('');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="modal"
        id="myModal"
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        data-bs-keyboard="false"
        tabIndex={-1}
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">TEST</h4>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close btn-close-white"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Id"
                value={inputid}
                onChange={handleIdInput}
              />
              <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Title"
                value={inputTitle}
                onChange={handleTitleInput}
              />
              <br />
              <button className="form-control" onClick={resetInputField}>
                Reset
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A* simple solution would be to introduce some state to the `App` component, updated by the test button being clicked, that could be passed to the `TestMOdalForm` to be used as an `useEffect` dependency.

It's also anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise-chains. Pick one or the other.

Example:

```
const App: FC<AppProps> = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#myModal"
        onClick={() => setId((c) => c + 1)} // <-- update state upon click
      >
        Test
      </button>
      <br />

      <TestModalForm id={id} /> // <-- pass state as prop
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
const TestModalForm = ({ id }) => { // <-- destructure prop
  ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
        );
        const data = await response.json();

        setInputid(data.id);
        setInputTitle(data.title);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any fetch rejections or other thrown errors
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [id]); // <-- pass prop as dependency

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

[image: Edit retrieve-the-latest-data-by-using-api-link]